# How can I download and use pypm gratis?

Tags: python, packaging, pinax, activepython, pypm

I have the community edition of ActiveState Python installed under Linux Mint 18.1, and do not see how to access PyPM. I have also attempted to install `python-pypm` through Mint's package manager

There is no `pypm` in `/opt/ActivePython-3.6'bin`, and there are no executables that appear visible under a `find / | grep -i pypm`. Documentation is easy enough to find online, but I've only found documentation of things you can do *after* you have a working pypm installation, not what you can do in order to *get* a working pypm installation.

My motivating goal is to get a working installation of [Pinax social](https://github.com/Stackato-Apps/pinax-social), but a `pip -r requirements.txt` is failing on the first attempted Pinax-specific download, and it after installing Django the user is told:

> The repository located at dist.pinaxproject.com is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host dist.pinaxproject.com'

So I have at least one thing set up wrong here. Would it suffice to getting a working `pypm`? Or is the case hopeless?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyPM has been discontinued and is no longer supported. `pip` is now the preferred method of managing and installing packages in ActivePython.

The warning about the source is likely due to the fact that it doesn't use HTTPS, and as the warning says you can silence that if you trust the host. Can't speak for the specifics of the Pinax install. Hope that helps!